# Formatting two different dataframes with POSIXct for left_join()-ing

Tags: r, posixct

I'm quite new to R and I'd like to `left_join()` the following two datasets:

```
> head(datagps)
   Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude            DateTime    meters
1:    18/06/2018 03:16 -2.434613  34.85372 2018-06-18 03:16:00 12.036834
2:    18/06/2018 03:20 -2.434511  34.85376 2018-06-18 03:20:00 18.738134
3:    18/06/2018 03:24 -2.434503  34.85393 2018-06-18 03:24:00 26.781879
4:    18/06/2018 03:28 -2.434719  34.85382 2018-06-18 03:28:00  8.341659
5:    18/06/2018 03:33 -2.434718  34.85375 2018-06-18 03:33:00 11.332758
6:    18/06/2018 03:36 -2.434817  34.85377 2018-06-18 03:36:00 15.736907
> head(datasensorraw)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  TimeGroup               x     y     z
  <dttm>              <int> <int> <dbl>
1 2018-06-09 04:48:00     3     5  5.83
2 2018-06-09 04:52:00     0     0  0   
3 2018-06-09 04:56:00    29    31 42.8 
4 2018-06-09 05:00:00    10     5 11.2 
5 2018-06-09 05:04:00     2    10 10.2 
6 2018-06-09 05:08:00     0     0  0
```

However, one of them is in `POSIXct` format and the other isn't, since I tried the code:

```
> dataresults<-left_join(datagps, datasensorraw, by = c("Date & Time [Local]" = "TimeGroup"))
Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches) : 
  cannot join a POSIXct object with an object that is not a POSIXct object
```

How to know which one of the two is in `POSIXct` format and how to format the other one so I can `left_join()` successfully? I've looked at other examples but I can't understand when `-` or `/` needs to be used.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: As the error says, convert the`Date & Time [Local] ` into POSIXct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the first dataset column `Date & Time [Local]` is not 'DateTime' class. Converting to POSIXct would solve the issue

```
library(dplyr)
datagps %>% 
      mutate(`Date & Time [Local]` = as.POSIXct(`Date & Time [Local]`, 
           format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
      left_join(datasensorraw, by = c("Date & Time [Local]" = "TimeGroup"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got:```> library(dplyr)
> datagps %>%
+ format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"datagps %>%
format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")"```

Comment: @juancda4  Sorry a typo, it should have an enclosing bracket at the end. updated